# How do I get jquery to ignore ids when filtering

Tags: jquery

I am searching all ids in a content div and prepending a href. I can't predict what the child ids will be so it prepends it anyway.

How do I get the jquery to search the dom but ignore cetain div's id and its children?

```
           $('*[id]').each(function() {
            var selectVariable = this;
            $(selectVariable).prepend('<a href="#" class="" id="' + $(selectVariable).attr('id') + '">*</a>');
        });

        <div id='content'>
             <!-- How do I stop the jquery from prepending  `id='I can predict'` and all its children-->
            <div id='I can predict'>
                 <div id='I can't predict'>
                 </div>

                  <div id='I can't predict'>
                  </div>
            </div>

            <div id='another piece of content'>
                  <div id='I can't predict (but needs an a link)'>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your example HTML has duplicate id values, and problems with unbalanced quotes.

Comment: Also spaces are not allowed in HTML id attribute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.not($('#I_can_predict, #I_can_predict *'))` to exclude the part you want out:

```js
$('*[id]').not($('#I_can_predict, #I_can_predict *')).each(function() {
    var selectVariable = this;
    $(selectVariable).prepend('<a href="#" class="" id="' 
                              + $(selectVariable).attr('id') + '">*</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='content'>
    content
     <!-- How do I stop the jquery from prepending  `id='I can predict'` and all its children-->
    <div id='I_can_predict'>I can predict
         <div id="I_can't_predict">I can't predict1
         </div>

          <div id="I_can't_predict2">I can't predict2
          </div>
    </div>

    <div id='another_piece_of_content'>another piece of content
          <div id="I_can't_predict_(but_needs_an_a_link)">I_can't_predict_(but_needs_an_a_link)
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried not($('#id, #id *')) but did not realise I could use * thanks work great

Answer (score 0):

Check if div has id "I_can_predict" or if any of its parents have this id:

```
if (!$(selectVariable).parents('#I_can_predict').length &&
    selectVariable.id != 'I_can_predict') {
       $(selectVariable).prepend('<a href="#" class="" id="' + $(selectVariable).attr('id') + '">*</a>');
    }
```

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7kmc09av/